# Looping through object in mvc view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my view :

```
@{
    var i = 0;
    var posts = Session["num"] as List<class_project.Models.Post>;
    if (posts != null)
    {
        foreach (object item in posts)
        {
             <p>@item</p>

        }
    }
}
```

As a result of this I am getting  : a couple of class_project.Models.Post strings.

How can I display my actual objects instead?
I tried with item.something, which doesn't really work.

Comment: can you post your class_project.Models.Post model

Comment: Instead of `foreach (object item in posts)` you should be able to write `foreach (class_project.Models.Post item in posts)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using object type "class_project.Models.Post" or "var" on your foreach
and properties on your template:

```
@{
    //var i = 0; //You can delete this variable.
    var posts = Session["num"] as List<class_project.Models.Post>;
    if (posts != null)
    {
        //foreach (class_project.Models.Post item in posts)
        //the same as "foreach (var item in posts)"
        foreach (var item in posts)
        {
             <p>@item.PropertyOne</p>
             <p>@item.PropertyTwo</p>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var` works equally well with less typing, since your `posts` collection is a strongly typed list.

Comment: Now, you can delete "var i = 0;"